# I want to change this Script on google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
var SHEET_NAME = ["1", "2", "3", "연습시트", "복사용"];

function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if( s.getName() == "1" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if( r.getColumn() == 1 ) { //checks the column
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 19);
      if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //is empty?
        nextCell.setNumberFormat("MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
        nextCell.setValue(new Date());
    }
  }
  if( s.getName() == "2" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if( r.getColumn() == 1 ) { //checks the column
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 19);
      if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //is empty?
        nextCell.setNumberFormat("MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
        nextCell.setValue(new Date());
    }
  }
  if( s.getName() == "3" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if( r.getColumn() == 1 ) { //checks the column
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 19);
      if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //is empty?
        nextCell.setNumberFormat("MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
        nextCell.setValue(new Date());
    }
  }
    if( s.getName() == "연습시트" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if( r.getColumn() == 1 ) { //checks the column
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 19);
      if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //is empty?
        nextCell.setNumberFormat("MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
        nextCell.setValue(new Date());
    }
  }
      if( s.getName() == "복사용" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if( r.getColumn() == 1 ) { //checks the column
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 19);
      if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //is empty?
        nextCell.setNumberFormat("MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
        nextCell.setValue(new Date());
    }
  }
}
```

with this script, to add more sheet, I need to add new sheet name and one bunch of code on the script.

So I wanna change them like, If sheet had Specific text of alphabet in his name, they automatically applied by this script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to repeat the same block of code over and over again. Just check if the edited sheet is in the array of 'sheetNames'. See if this helps

```js
 function onEdit(e) {
  const sheetNames = ["1", "2", "3", "연습시트", "복사용"];
  const sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if (sheetNames.includes(sheet.getName()) && e.range.columnStart === 1) {
    const offset = e.range.offset(0, 19)
    if (!offset.getValue()) {
      offset.setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I Just applied yours and it's working
THANK YOU

Comment: Glad to hear ! In that case, please consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) or/and upvote. Cheers !